# mediawiki online wysiwyg editor or preview tool

Tags: documentation, github, mediawiki, markdown, markup

I'm looking for an online tool I can use to preview MediaWiki markup output.

Here are some examples of what I'm looking for (only these are for reST, not mediawiki):

http://rst.ninjs.org/

http://www.tele3.cz/jbar/rest/rest.html

This arose from a need to preview my README.mediawiki files on github before committing them. See here for details: https://github.com/github/markup

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, you can preview the .mediawiki straight on github: either in it's wiki service (all pages have the “preview” button in the bottom and it have mediawiki as one of its formats), or in the online file editor, it have the “preview” tab near the “code” one.